# append a large number of data.frame in R

Tags: r

I have some unknown number of data frames that need to be glued together into a long single data frame.

```
set.seed(0)
N <- floor(rnorm(1,100,2))

for(i in 1:N){
  assign(paste('X', i, sep=''), data.frame(O=rnorm(1,100,2)))
}
```

Now I want to make a data frame with N rows and 1 column by combine the data frames X1 - XN together.

How can I do that?

EDIT:

Following Roland suggestions I switched to list:

```
set.seed(0)
N <- floor(rnorm(1,100,2))


XP <- list()

for(i in 1:N){
  XP[[i]] <- data.frame(O=rnorm(1,100,2))
}
```

I am still not sure about the next step..

Comment: This would be incredibly easy if those data.frames were all together in one list as they should be. Forget that assign exists until you are a much more advanced R programmer. And then you'll probably not need it anymore.

Comment: @Roland I switched to list, but I am not sure the function to concentrate all elements in a list

Comment: if you stick to the list approach: `do.call(rbind,XP)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I already said in the comments, you can use `do.call` which works perfectly with the list approach from @Roland.

```
do.call(rbind,XP)
```